# restful_authentication hash problem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, restful-authentication

I work with restful_authentication on my website. Here's my problem:

If I am not logged in and go the page http://mywebsite.com/something#coolHash

I get redirected to http://mywebsite.com/session/new and I log in.

But after that I get redirected to http://mywebsite.com/something but without the Hash which would be very important.

Is there a possibility to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this as part of restful_authentication's regular url-forwarding system, because the browser strips off the part after the # before sending the request to the server.  So, if the server never sees #coolHash then it can't save it into the session and retrieve it later on, after the user logs in.  This would be a problem whatever server-based authentication you were using since the server never sees #coolHash (have a look in your access logs to see what request urls are actually recieved to verify this).

You *could* potentially solve the problem with javascript, i'm not sure what the nicest way would be.  But, my advice would be to change your approach so that you don't care if #coolHash is remembered or not (any after-the-hash stuff should just be an enhancement to basically-works-fine behaviour anyway).  For example, use a param instead of putting stuff after the hash.  The param *will* be stored automatically by restful authentication.